# How do I expand this replace expression to add weird alpha characters like "ü"?

Tags: java, android, regex

I have this replacement expression here:

```
 String firstName = mFirstName.getText().toString().trim().replace(" ", "");
 String lastName = mLastName.getText().toString().trim().replace(" ", "");

 firstName = firstName.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z'-]", "");
 lastName = lastName.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z'-]", "");
```

It works really well and quickly. However it doesn't allow for the international ascii characters 128-165, say like umlauts. But I don't want the characters after that "()|-" in the string to be included. Is there a way to include that all in one replace all, or do I have to separate it out into multiple expressions?

Here's what I've tried (unsuccessfully) :

```
    firstName = firstName.replaceAll("[^A-Za-zÀ-Ÿ'-]", "");
    lastName = lastName.replaceAll("[^Alpha'-]", "");
```

It still replaces the characters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`\p{L}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) which matches any Unicode character which is *letter*.

```
String strUmlaut = "ÀèŸ";
System.out.println(strUmlaut.matches("\\p{L}+"));
```

***OUTPUT***

```
true
```

Answer (score 1):

`[^A-Za-z\\x80-\\xa5'-]` will additionally match characters with ASCII codes 128-165 (80 - A5 in hex)